# chrome float css hover only on last element

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover

maybe my title is not very clear but I will just paste the link to my site:

http://kaohsiung.at/

please have a look at the square buttons in the menu. if I use firefox it works as intended. if you hover over them they flip and you can see the menu text.

but if i use chrome then only the last buttons flips.

the strange thing is that it worked all the time until recently. but i cannot figure out what the problem is. so maybe someone can help me. I will not post the html and css code as you can use chrome to inspect it.

Edit:

Ok I reduced the css and the html to a minimum here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/KVBQU/17/

html:

```
   <nav id="access" role="navigation">


<div class="menuentry">
        <div class="menuentrycontainer">
            <div class="menutext">
            <p>Home</p>
            </div>      
            <div class="menuimage">
                test
                </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="menuentry">
        <div class="menuentrycontainer">
            <div class="menutext">
            <p>Home</p>
            </div>      
           <div class="menuimage">
                test
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="menuentry">
        <div class="menuentrycontainer">
            <div class="menutext">
            <p>Party</p>
            </div>      
            <div class="menuimage">
                test
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>

<div class="menuentry"> 
        <div class="menuentrycontainer">
        <div class="menutext">
        <p>Kunst</p>
        </div>      
        <div class="menuimage">
                test
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div id="clearfloatdiv"></div>        

</nav><!-- #access -->
```

css:

```
#access {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    z-index: 1000000
    }

.menuentry {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 8.33%;
    padding-top: 8.33%;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
    }

.menuentrycontainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0
    }

.menutext {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    background-color: rgb(124, 172, 231);
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    -moz-transform: rotatey(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotatey(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotatey(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(270deg);
    transform: rotatey(270deg);
    border: solid white 2px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
    }

.menutext p {
    padding-top: 15px
    }

.menuimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgb(124, 172, 231);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-out 200ms;
    border: solid green 2px
    }

.menutext {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-out
    }

.menuentrycontainer:hover .menuimage {
    -moz-transform: rotatey(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotatey(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotatey(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(90deg);
    transform: rotatey(90deg);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in
    }

.menuentrycontainer:hover .menutext {
    -moz-transform: rotatey(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotatey(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotatey(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(360deg);
    transform: rotatey(360deg);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in 200ms
    }

#clearfloatdiv {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: just checked in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 - works fine

Comment: off topic - `Or you diabled cookies` - should be disabled?

Comment: I've Version 27.0.1453.94 (latest) and it's broken as described.

Comment: The hover/transition does not work in Opera, but seems okay in Safari and IE (latest versions).

Comment: It is hard to isolate the issue, is it transition part of the CSS, or how the hover pseudo-class is interacting with the absolutely positioned elements?  We need a simplified example to make this question more generally useful.

Comment: thank you for all the answers i really have no clue what happened - I copied the nav code into jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KVBQU/ same issue. my chrome version is 27.0.1453.94 m